# Examples of planning and search usage

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence, planning

What are applications where search techniques or more specifically planning techniques are used? I am most interested in examples in use.

I know that A* is used for path planning in Robotics, that planning is used in logistics (details would be great) but what other usages are there?

For Search in general Google, etc come to mind with their inverted indices. Again, where else is it used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For planning examples, including logistics challenges, take a look at [this list](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#examplesOverview). Each use case comes with multiple datasets and a problem definition.